# Exception to throw when expecting a null value?

Tags: c#, exception

If I am expecting a null value and get a defined value (within a getter of a property) and want to throw an exception, what would be the proper way to do this in csharp? Is there anything defined already that makes sense in this situation?

Comment: @Joe As an aside designs which rely on null values can be a potential maintenance issue, as every new use of members which can return null have to check for it. It is often desirable to have a design which avoids this.

Comment: That is an unusual arrangement, unless you have it set up as an *out* parameter (otherwise why even worry about receiving that parameter?). What are the side effects of setting it to null if it isn't?

Comment: Just out of curiosity could you tell us why you're mandating a null value?

Comment: I also want to know why you would ever want to do this?  If you always want null, i.e., a known value, just don't take the parameter in the first place.

Comment: I have two variables where I only expect at most one to be set when getting the current value from either of the two locations. For instance, one location could be from a config file and another could be from code and it only makes sense for the user to have set the value once.

Comment: @Joe: So you basically want to throw an exception if there is an erroneous configuration and not if a value is null. I'd rather go for something like `ConfigurationErrorException` then or a custom exception expressing that fact.

Answer (score 8):

My guess would be:

```
throw new
    ArgumentException("Parameter was expected to be null, value was provided.");
```

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` might also work, but is typically used when there is a well defined range rather than null vs. not null.

Comment: +1 Throwing your own exception gives you the ability to provide "human-readable" errors that make sense when the user sees them.  Contextualizing errors is the best approach.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen `InvalidOperationException` used, as in the context of trying to set something twice.  For example,

```
if(displayMessage != null)
  throw new InvalidOperationException("The display message may not be set more than once.");

displayMessage = myAwesomeMessage;
```