# Throwing ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#

Is it a good idea to throw ArgumentNullException() when having a null value? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400818/exception-to-throw-when-expecting-a-null-value) thread doesn't mention the most obvious exception to throw on a null.

Thanks

Comment: In that thread the asker of the question is expecting a null as an argument though (which as the comments suggest does smell). In that specific case it is not an exception scenario, he want's to throw an exception when the argument is non-null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) should only be used when the parameter to a method is found to be null:

```
public void MyMethod(MyClass cannotBeNull)
{
    if (cannotBeNull == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cannotBeNull");
    }
    // Do something useful
}
```

Comment: See Code Analysis rule [CA1062: Validate arguments of public methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are reading it backwards, the other scenerio posses the situation:

> *If I am expecting a null value and get a defined value*

If you look at the [MSDN: ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx) it is specifically for

> *The exception that is thrown when a null reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) is passed to a method that does
>   not accept it as a valid argument.*

I am expecting a null and I get something

vs.

I am expecting something and I get null

That said, there is no reason you can not, or should not, create your own

```
public class IWantANullException:Exception
```

and throw it around in what ever way you wish.